# NuGet Dependency Hell

Tags: dependencies, nuget, nuget-package

i have a small question regard a own NuGet server and own NuGet packages which we are pushing to it.
We have several projects and a adapted TFS build process which is pushing NuGet packages automatically to our NuGet server - so far it is working very well.

Currently we are asking ourself if this is a good solution:
Our main project is using dependency injection to resolve dependencies.
Therefore we have a project structure like:

- Interfaces (.dll)
- DataLayer (.dll)
- Localization (.dll)
- Infrastructure (.dll)
- Application (.exe)

In my opinion i would like to split up the things into more, smaller solutions to keep the things simple and easy to use:

- Interfaces (only one project: the Interface definitions)
- Compontents (three projects: with DataLayer, Localization and Infrastructure)
- Application (only one project: only the exe)

This lead us to the problem that if somebody is changing the interfaces we would have to update the nuget-packet-version of the interfaces within every components project, commit changes to our build system, and afterwards update the application itself. It´s a little bit like DLL Hell - in addition debugging and developing is a little bit hard if you try that because of the several projects whcih are seperated.

Is this structure bullshit? What is in your opinion a good option to solve the dependencies and to reduce and unwrap large solutions into smaller ones? Or would you recommend to consolidate all projects into one large solution?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are recommending "if somebody is changing the interfaces we would have to update the nuget-packet-version of the interfaces within every components project, commit changes to our build system" is actually not the best practice and will cause problems as you scale.

Ideally, you want to separate the development of packages from the development of the consumer. Consider your component package and the application layer. If you have a current set up where the Application project is consuming 1.0.0.0 of your Components package. Somebody goes in and adds a new component to the Components package and creates a version 1.1.0.0. Now if you go in and update Components package in Application project, the following things will happen

1. Any bug fixes included in the new components packages gets brought in (which might be a good thing)
2. Any new components added to the package will be available to the application project (this is a good thing only if the Application is going to consume the new component else it does not impact Application at all)
3. Any new bugs that were added in the process of creating the new component that might have inadvertently impacted the functionality of the existing components also get pulled in.

In my opinion, point #3 is the most dangerous impact of the package update. Whenever I know that newer version of the package is going to fix a bug or introduce new functionality THAT I NEED in application, I am ok with risking addition of new bugs. However, if I am not going to use the new components, I would basically be introducing instability in the Application project for no added advantage.

Process I would recommend-

1. Separate the development of each package from its consumer. This approach scales pretty well and gives the consumer the option to OPT-IN to new changes.
2. Create some system/convention where the developers of the package can let the consumer know when there is a new version being released. Proper release notes/a simple blog could also suffice.
3. Have developers of the Application/projects that consumes the new package pull in the latest version only when it contains functionality that is needed by the consumer